# Save incoming PDF in WebView to Memory

Tags: ios, pdf, swift2, xcode7.1

I have a project that is associated with opening PDF files.  This is set in the `Info.plist`.  When I get a PDF attachment in email, I can hold my finger on the PDF attachment and then 'Open in' in my app.  In my `AppDelegate`, I have the following added:

```
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
    incomingTransfer = URL
    return true
}
```

`incomingTransfer` is a `Global Variable` declared in another `ViewController` as an `NSURL`.  This `ViewController` also has a `UIWebView` and the `incomingTransfer` loads into it and I'm able to see the new PDF file.  My goal is to have a button that allows the user to save the incoming PDF as a PDF.  I'm having trouble with this. I thought I had it all figured out, but it wasn't saving as a PDF at all, but rather as a `String`. Can someone help me please?  My goal is to save the incoming PDF file as a PDF to the app memory, preferably in `DocumentDirectory`.  I have a hard time trying to convert Objective C to Swift. My original code to save it was:

```
    let html = String(incomingFileTransfer)
    let fmt = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: html)

    let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()
    render.addPrintFormatter(fmt, startingAtPageAtIndex: 0)

    let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595.2, height: 841.8) // A4, 72 dpi
    let printable = CGRectInset(page, 0, 0)

    render.setValue(NSValue(CGRect: page), forKey: "paperRect")
    render.setValue(NSValue(CGRect: printable), forKey: "printableRect")

    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRectZero, nil)

    for i in 1...render.numberOfPages() {

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        let bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()
        render.drawPageAtIndex(i - 1, inRect: bounds)
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    recipeFileName = fileName.text!

    print("File Name Entered: \(recipeFileName)")

    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]

    pdfData.writeToFile("\(documentsPath)/\(recipeFileName).pdf", atomically: true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I created a `class` called 'PDFFile'.  Within 'PDFFile' are two `variables`, named `var name: String` and `var url: NSURL`.  Within my 'IncomingTransfer' `ViewController`, I have the 'save' `button` create and save the new file with a typed name from the `UITextField` and the incomingURL specified in my `AppDelegate` is assigned to the `url` `variable`.  Both are then saved to the `PDFFile` class using `NSCoding`.  I then set a `UITableView` for it's `dataSource` from the PDFFile `Class` `array` data.  I created a `segue` when the user clicks on the `UITableViewCell` and that goes to a new `ViewController` with a `UIWebView`.  This `WebView` loads the PDF from a `urlRequest` using the specified `url` variable, saved from the `NSCoding`.

`AppDelegate` Code:

```
// Allows incoming file access (PDF)
func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {

    // Transfer incoming file to global variable to be read

    if url != "" {

        // Load from Mail App

        incomingFileTransfer = url

        incomingStatus = "Incoming"

    } else {

        // Regular Load

        print("App Delegate: No incoming file")

        incomingFileTransfer = nil

    }        

    return true
}
```

IncomingFile code and save `button` code:

```
// MARK: Properties
var file: PDFFile?

// MARK: Actions
// Save Button
let name = fileName.text ?? ""

let url = incomingFileTransfer

file = PDFFile(name: name, url: url)


// MARK: NSCoding
func saveFiles() {

    let isSuccessfulSave = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(pdfFiles, toFile: PDFFile.ArchiveURL.path!)

    if !isSuccessfulSave {

        print("Failed to save PDF file")

    }

}
```

Viewing Saved Incoming PDF Later `ViewController` code:
    // MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var pdfItemWebView: UIWebview!

```
var incomingURL: NSURL!

// Within ViewDidLoad
    if let file = file {

        pdfFileName.text = file.name

        incomingURL = file.url

        print("Saved URL: \(incomingURL)")

        print("Pending load...")

        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: incomingURL!)

        pdfItemWebView.loadRequest(request)

    }
```

It was complicated but worked for me.  There may be an easier way, but this is what I figured out and its works for my needs.